# Dynamically generated button which toggles from dictionary value doesn't toggle

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have written a function which creates a button that adds a row to a datagridview table with given values (Which it does) and then allows the user to click a button on the datagridview to remove the item, but not click the button again. The function currently only allows one of the 4 dynamically generated buttons to operate, after that it stops working.

```
    Public promoItems As New Dictionary(Of String, Object)

    Public strID As Integer
    Public strName As String
    Public strPrice As Integer
    Public strOptions As String

    Sub loadPromoItems()
            Dim promoButton As New Button
            strID = 1 
            strPrice = 1
            strOptions = "Options"
            strName = "Name"
            promoItems(strID) = False
            promoButton.Tag = {strName, strOptions, strPrice, strID}
            AddHandler promoButton.Click, Sub()

                                              Dim btn = DirectCast(promoButton, Button)
                                              Dim data = DirectCast(btn.Tag, String())
                                              If promoItems(strID) = False Then 
                                                  DataGridView.Rows.Add(data(0), data(1), "$", "×", data(2), "True", data(3))
                                                  promoItems(strID) = True
                                              End If
                                          End Sub
            FlowLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(promoButton)

    End Sub
```

The above function generates the buttons, and when they are clicked it adds one row as expected, but only one of the dynamically generated buttons work at any given time.

```
    Private Sub DataGridView_CellContentClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView.CellContentClick
        If e.ColumnIndex = 3 Then 'If the × button has been pressed
            Dim row As DataGridViewRow = DataGridView.Rows(e.RowIndex) 'define row as row that button has been clicked
            If row.Cells(5).Value = True Then 'if the row cell 5 is True
                promoItems(row.Cells(6).Value) = False 'allow item to be clicked again
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
```

The above block deletes the row from the datagridview and then should allow the dynamically generated button to be clicked again, but doesn't.

Comment: Are strID, strPrice, strOptions, and strName declared somewhere? What are the datatypes of each one?

Comment: Your Function lacks a Return statement. What Double is it going to return?

Comment: They can only be declared as one type. Can we see the declarations?

Comment: Also show the declare and initialization of promoItems

Comment: I've amended the code, showing declarations.

Comment: How do you think you can assign 1 to a String. 1 is an Integer not a string! Turn on Option Strict

Comment: I changed `Public promoItems As New Dictionary(Of String, Object)` to `Integer` instead of  `String` and the error persists.

Comment: I was referring to `strID = 1` not the dictionary.  `strID` is declared as a `String` and you are trying to assign an `Integer` to it.

Comment: The error still persists. After I tested again, it seems the error lies with the value of strID always being set to the last value. For example, each button should have the value 1-4, but instead they are all set to 4.

Comment: You still haven't added a Return to your Function. There are so many errors in your code. We are just working our way down. Have you fixed `strID = 1` and  `strPrice = 1` ?

Comment: Yeah, they are both integers. I don't think I need a return, though?

Comment: Then don't use a Function use a Sub. So that As Double was totally bogus. You must have had something in mind when you wrote that. You did write this, didn't you? So both of your declares for strID and strPrice are incorrect and your dictionary definition is wrong also.

Comment: Also `promoButton.Tag = {strName, strOptions, strPrice, strID}` will not work because since the data is different types the type cannot be inferred.

Answer (score 0):

This is as close as I can get. If it helps, great. If not perhaps someone else can get you closer.

```
Private strID As Integer
Private strName As String
Private strPrice As Integer
Private strOptions As String
Private promoItems As New Dictionary(Of Integer, Object)


Sub loadPromoItems()
    Dim promoButton As New Button
    strID = 1
    strPrice = 1
    strOptions = "Options"
    strName = "Name"
    'I like the more traditional way of adding items to a dictionary
    'promoItems.Add(strID, False)
    promoItems(strID) = False
    Dim TagObject() As Object = {strName, strOptions, strPrice, strID}
    promoButton.Tag = TagObject
    AddHandler promoButton.Click, AddressOf PromoButton_Click
    FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(promoButton)
End Sub

Private Sub PromoButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim btn = DirectCast(sender, Button)
    Dim data = DirectCast(btn.Tag, Object())
    If CBool(promoItems(strID)) = False Then
        DataGridView1.Rows.Add(data(0), data(1), "$", "×", data(2), "True", data(3))
        promoItems(strID) = True
    End If
End Sub
```